# XML Inventory System

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to test an inventory system I'm making, but I want to make it with XML.
putting in the codes and such like:

```
    <Item>
  <ItemName ItemName = "Apple">
    <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    <ItemMaxQuantity>64</ItemMaxQuantity>
    <ItemState>PERFECT</ItemState>
  </ItemName>

  <ItemName ItemName = "Sword">
    <ItemQuantity>1</ItemQuantity>
    <ItemMaxQuantity>1</ItemMaxQuantity>
    <ItemState>BROKEN</ItemState>
  </ItemName>
</Item>
```

I know how to Serialize and such. But don't know how to further put them in the game, having multiple items like I've shown.
I have an inventory class. 
That's like this:

```
namespace inventory_test
{
    class Inventory
    {
        public enum ItemState
        {
            NONE,
            PERFECT,
            FINE,
            BROKEN,
            DESTROYED
        };

        /*public enum ItemType
        {
            FOOD,
            USEABLE,
            WEAPON,
            KEY,
            TOOL
        }; Implement this in the test later*/

        [XmlElement("ItemName")]
        public string ItemName
        { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ItemState")]
        public string ItemState
        { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ItemQuantity")]
        public string Quantity
        { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ItemMaxQuantity")]
        public string MaxQuantity
        { get; set; }

        static void AddItem(int itemID, string itemState, int quantity, int maxquantity)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

This is my program.cs:

```
    namespace inventory_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
//Serialization
        static public void Serialize(Inventory inventory)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Inventory));
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, inventory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what I have to do now.
I'm really stuck right now and don't know what to to do.
Help me :)?

Comment: what is the question? You want to deserialize the xml content to list of `Inventory` object?

Comment: Thats kinda what I want to do, yeah. With attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This example code shows you how to serialize List of Inventory to xml file, and how to read the file and generate the same List of Inventory.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Inventory>));
var inventories = new List<Inventory>();
inventories.Add(new Inventory
{
    ItemName = "Apple",
    Quantity = "1",
    MaxQuantity = "64",
    ItemState = "PERFECT"
});
inventories.Add(new Inventory
{
    ItemName = "Sword",
    Quantity = "1",
    MaxQuantity = "1",
    ItemState = "BROKEN"
});
//write to xml file
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("inventory.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, inventories);
}
//read from xml file and generate List<Inventory>
using (var reader = new StreamReader("inventory.xml"))
{
    //variable 'result' will contain the same value as 'inventories'
    var result = (List<Inventory>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: That's not really what I want though, I want to write the name, description, state of the item in XML and then port it to the code itself :)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment in my previous answer, meant you don't want to do it with serialize/deserialize approach but "manual" approach isntead. You can write and read xml file "manually" using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and linq-to-xml query. This is the example :

```
//writing to xml file
var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no"));
var root = new XElement("Item");
doc.Add(root);
foreach (var inventory in inventories)
{
    var itemNode = new XElement("ItemName");
    var itemAttribute = new XAttribute("ItemName", inventory.ItemName);
    itemNode.Add(itemAttribute);
    var itemQty = new XElement("ItemQuantity", inventory.Quantity);
    itemNode.Add(itemQty);
    var itemMaxQty = new XElement("ItemMaxQuantity", inventory.MaxQuantity);
    itemNode.Add(itemMaxQty);
    var itemState = new XElement("ItemState", inventory.ItemState);
    itemNode.Add(itemState);
    root.Add(itemNode);
}
doc.Save("Inventory.xml");

//reading from xml file created by above codes to create List<Inventory> object
var docFromFile = XDocument.Load("Inventory.xml");
var inventoriesFromFile = (from inventory in docFromFile.Descendants("ItemName")
                       select new Inventory
                                  {
                                      ItemName = inventory.Attribute("ItemName").Value,
                                      Quantity = inventory.Element("ItemQuantity").Value,
                                      MaxQuantity = inventory.Element("ItemMaxQuantity").Value,
                                      ItemState = inventory.Element("ItemState").Value
                                  }).ToList();

//in the end you'll get variable inventories and inventoriesFromFile have same value
```

Note that `inventories` variable in the code above is the same as in my previous answer (definition and content/value). Also in the question, you only showed some knowledge/effort on `XmlSerializer` not on `XDocument` stuff, so read the codes carefully. There will be too much thing to write if you expect me to explain every single line of code in this answer. Good Luck